# Is IPA the correct alcohol to clean my windshield?

Tags: cleaning, windshield

I have somewhat a substantial amount of gunk spots (probably dust, pollen and liquefied bugs etc.) accumulated  my windshield. Washed the windshield with car shampoo bunch of times but to no avail.
Is isopropyl alcohol (IPA) the correct type of cleaner for this purpose or shall I use denatured alcohol?

Comment: Depending on what the gunk is made up of, the IPA should handle it. You might end up needing a razor blade to clean it off. Scrape it like you would when cleaning stickers off your windshield.

Comment: WD-40 is often helpful in softening sun-dried gunk.  Then IPA can help get it clean after that.

Comment: @jwh20 - That's actually a great suggestion. WD40 was actually developed to clean aircraft skins, so should work well as you suggested. Not sure if it is readily available where the OP lives, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I believe WD-40 is marketed worldwide.  But if not, I am sure there are similar products available just about anywhere.

Comment: @jwh20 - Nah, there is no replacement for WD40, didntchaknow? :P